# Symfony2 FOSUserBundle disable both, email confirmation and user on registration

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I just want to make it that when the user registers. He does not get any email. Of course I can do that by making this:

```
registration:
    confirmation:
        enabled: false
```

However this makes a user automatically register with no confirmation.

I want to make it so that when a User registers he has to wait until the admin enables the user. That means i need to make the user be Disabled by default..

I cant find any information regarding that. Can someone help?

I tried this but it didnt work:

User.php

```
  public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    // your own logic

        $this->enabled = false;
    //and
        $this->setEnabled(false);
    }
```

P.S Together with FOS i am using the SonataUserBundle.. This is my registerAction:

```
 public function registerAction()
    {
        $user = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
        if ($user instanceof UserInterface) {
            $this->container->get('session')->getFlashBag()->set('sonata_user_error', 'sonata_user_already_authenticated');
            $url = $this->container->get('router')->generate('sonata_user_profile_show');
            return new RedirectResponse($url);
        }
        $form = $this->container->get('sonata.user.registration.form');
        $formHandler = $this->container->get('sonata.user.registration.form.handler');
        $confirmationEnabled = $this->container->getParameter('fos_user.registration.confirmation.enabled');

        $process = $formHandler->process($confirmationEnabled);
        if ($process) {
            $user = $form->getData();

            $authUser = false;
            if ($confirmationEnabled) {
                $this->container->get('session')->set('fos_user_send_confirmation_email/email', $user->getEmail());
                $url = $this->container->get('router')->generate('fos_user_registration_check_email');
            } else {
                $authUser = true;
                $route = $this->container->get('session')->get('sonata_basket_delivery_redirect');

                if (null !== $route) {
                    $this->container->get('session')->remove('sonata_basket_delivery_redirect');
                    $url = $this->container->get('router')->generate($route);
                } else {
                    $url = $this->container->get('session')->get('sonata_user_redirect_url');
                }
            }

            $this->setFlash('fos_user_success', 'registration.flash.user_created');

            $response = new RedirectResponse($url);

            if ($authUser) {
                $this->authenticateUser($user, $response);
            }

            return $response;
        }

        $this->container->get('session')->set('sonata_user_redirect_url', $this->container->get('request')->headers->get('referer'));

        return $this->container->get('templating')->renderResponse('MpShopBundle:Frontend:registration.html.'.$this->getEngine(), array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }
```

**UPDATE**

The only way I can make this work is by enabling the email confirmation, but not sending the email to the user. This way a user cant confirm his account and has to wait until the admin will enable it. But I dont whant to have such problems.. There should be a way to disable them normally.

**FIXED**

I finally figured it out. All you had to to is in the registerAction in the code where check if i need email confirmation, in the else statement to set it to enabled and update the user. If you dont update it it wont work.

```
if ($process) {
            $user = $form->getData();

            $authUser = false;
            if ($confirmationEnabled) {
                $this->container->get('session')->set('fos_user_send_confirmation_email/email', $user->getEmail());
                $url = $this->container->get('router')->generate('fos_user_registration_check_email');
            } else {
                $user->setEnabled(false);
                $userManager = $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager');
                $userManager->updateUser($user);
                $route = $this->container->get('session')->get('sonata_basket_delivery_redirect');

                if (null !== $route) {
                    $this->container->get('session')->remove('sonata_basket_delivery_redirect');
                    $url = $this->container->get('router')->generate($route);
                } else {
                    $url = $this->container->get('session')->get('sonata_user_redirect_url');
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try using `@ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()` in your user entity then you define a method, like:

```
/**
* @ORM\PrePersist
*/
public function yourMethod(){
    $this->setEnabled(false);
}
```

This works for me.

Answer (score 1):

The line `$this->setEnabled = true;` should probably be `$this->setEnabled(true);`.

In any case, I don't think this will work because the user is enabled in `\FOS\UserBundle\Controller\RegistrationController` on lines `43` and `114` explicitly with:

```
$user->setEnabled(true);
```

Therefore I expect that there is no configuration setting for this, so you would have to override the `RegistrationController` with your own logic to set a user as disabled.

This is pretty straightforward, here's the relevant documentation:

- https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_controllers.md

There's also some information in the documentation about hooking into controllers using events, which could be a viable alternative approach:

- https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/controller_events.md

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. Unfortunately I have already tried that. I forgot to mention that I am using SonataUserBundle too. I have updated my answer with the registrationAction. Take a look at it.

Comment: Ah... okay, I have never used `SonataUserBundle` so I am not really sure what the issue is in that case. Sorry about that.